# Iterating through every tableView cells with data source

Tags: swift, function, uitableview, core-data, datasource

I am trying to `iterate` through every `cell` in my `tableView` to make a calculation with the `amountValue` values.

I wrote a working method iterating through the `tableView` and not `data source`, some of you were not pleased haha.

**How can I translate this into a `data source` iteration?**

```
    // CryptosMO is the Managed Object with an `NSNumber` `amountValue` attribute among others.

    var item : [CryptosMO] = []

    if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        item = CDHandler.fetchObject()
    }

    for section in 0...self.tableView.numberOfSections {

        if (self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) > 1) {
            for row in 0...self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
                let indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)

                if item[indexPath.row].amountValue != nil {
                    let total = item[indexPath.row].amountValue.doubleValue + item[indexPath.row + 1].amountValue.doubleValue
                    print("TOTAL :", total)

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why iterating tableview to get total? not data source?

Comment: @mnemonic23 Thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I am trying to do. Could you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate total without for loop.

```
let total = dataSource.reduce(0.0, { $0 + ($1.amountValue.doubleValue) } )
```

maybe your dataSource is 'item' ?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! I need to read more about `data source` and `map` / `reduce`, this looks powerful!